# Adding data to a tableView using a NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I'm having a problem adding an item to my tableView.

I used to initialize an empty tableView at the start of my App and get it filled with scanned items every time the tableView reappears and there is an item in my variable.

Initialization of the tableView:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];
self.listArray = array;
```

TableView Data Source:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.listArray count];
}
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    if(section == 0)
        return @"Eingescannte Artikel:";
    else
        return nil;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"testCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    // Configure the cell...
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [listArray objectAtIndex:row];//[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Das ist Zeile %i", indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

(Not the whole thing but the ones I changed)

As you may have seen I use an NSMutableArray to add items to my tableView.

So if an item ist scanned I'm adding it to my array like this:

```
[listArray insertObject:sharedGS.strEAN atIndex:0]; //using a shared Instance where I implemented my variable.
```

I also tried to use an variable to extend my Index every time a new Item is added, but it won't work both ways.

I'm quite new to programming so an not-too-hard-to-understand-answer would be quite nice ;)

If there's any information missing, feel free to ask.

/edit: Trying to specify my question: The data from the variable is written in a TableViewCell, but if I scan another one the other one is just being replaced. Not sure if it's a problem with my array or my tableView...

/edit No.2: Found out(thanks to fzwo) that my array isn't working correctly. It just doesn't grow by an addObject: or insertObject:atIndex: command. But I just don't get why... :(
All I'm doing: `[listArray addObject:sharedGS.strEAN];` not that much space for errors in one simple line. Maybe I'm just too stupid to recognize what I'm doing wrong:D

Comment: Are you sure your array is growing? Put `NSLog(@"Anzahl der EAN-Codes: %d\nErster Code: %@", listArray.count, [listArray objectAtIndex:0]);` wherever you're calling `[tableView reloadData]`.

Comment: Ah! Looks like it isn't growing at all. But using the addObject or insertObject:atIndex: method should force the array to grow, or am I wrong?

Comment: You're right, it should grow. Maybe you're accidentally removing objects somewhere else?

Comment: Searched my project for my "listArray" but found no removing except in my-(void)"tableViewEditingMethod"(but afaik it's ok there). BUT I'm filling my array with testData in my viewDidLoad-method. As I understood it's just loaded once and afterwards the viewWillAppear method will take its place but this would be the only place to reset my array every time the view gets loaded (sort of self fail). Does it need to be in an -(void) init?

Comment: `init` is called exactly once in the lifetime of an object: At the beginning. `viewDidLoad` is usually only called once in the lifetime of a ViewController. `viewWillAppear` is called when the ViewController's view is about to appear on screen. Depending on your architecture, it can be called once, many times, or not at all. If I had to take a guess, I'd say it is probably only called once in your code, but it's impossible to say without more info. Make sure you update your Array and TableView whenever there's new data. Use NSLog or breakpoints to find out how often your update code is called.

Comment: I just had an idea: Maybe you are instantiating a new ViewController every time a barcode is scanned. How often does your NSLog show? If more than once, add this: `NSLog(@"%@", self)`. Is the number always the same, or is it different? If it's different, you create and present a new ViewController every time, and of course that one doesn't know about the old one's listArray.

Comment: <ShoppingList: 0x28ec80> on startup
<ShoppingList: 0x2c1f40> after scanning the first barcode

Guess its instantiating? Looking to get that fixed...

Comment: That's the memory address of the object; it's meaningless to me. The question is: Do you see this once, or more than once? If only once, that's your problem: Of course you want to see it every time you add a new code. If more than once: Is the number the same? (within one launch of the app; it may well be another number on the next launch)

Comment: Right, after your edit: Yes, your problem is that you're not reusing your ViewController. You create a new one every time you scan a Code. So now you have 2 ViewControllers, each one containing exactly one Code.

Comment: Ah that helps...a bit :D so I'm searching for the place where the new controller is created. Knowing I didn't write it, it has to be somewhere in the ZBarScanner Files I implemented.

Comment: Good idea! (By the way, it is good form to upvote helpful answers and comments. I think @valexa's answer was helpful enough, considering the little info he had available)

Comment: Well I'd love to vote him up, but right now I'm not allowed to due to a lack of reputation. :( Selecting it as the "right answer" hadn't been my choice because I feared no one else would give me feedback afterwards. Actually I'm not able to find the creation of a new controller... Using storyboards I guess pushing one View to another is creating a new view itself? Love to vote you up too, but you don't even have a real post i could vote. :)

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you with storyboards. I've always preferred to create all my views and controllers in code, I find it more easy to see what is happening that way. But the log clearly shows you're not reusing one controller, and that's not a good thing (even though you could keep your list outside the controller, so that it's shared among them all, it's still not really elegant not to reuse a controller, IMHO). (That's OK with the votes, I don't need the reputation. I just thought I'd tell you.).

Comment: Gave him the point anyway guessing no storyboard-guy will read this whole thing and gives helpful feedback. I think I'll try find a programmer in my company, beating him until he helps me with my code :) So thank you both very much, I still learned a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state that your problem is "adding an item to my tableView" , since you are adding the object to your array i am guessing the problem is that you are not reloading the table or that it is missing the dataSource binding.

You have not actually asked any question (even if you added info to "specify your question") so a wild guess, after

```
[listArray insertObject:sharedGS.strEAN atIndex:0];
```

put

```
[yourTableView reloadData];
```

Are you intentionally adding new items to the top of the table ? otherwise you could do
`[listArray addObject:sharedGS.strEAN];` to add new items to the bottom

Otherwise it's worth noting that you are misusing dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier, look at the example below for proper usage:

```
// Try to retrieve from the table view a now-unused cell with the given identifier
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

// If no cell is available, create a new one using the given identifier
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: don't know if it changed anything but they're still replacing each other :(
@dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: I'm using the new storyboard to create my tableView and added a prototype cell. Not sure, but I think I read somewhere this method is implemented automatically. Anyway I'll try it!

Comment: Well I found your
"UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier]"
in my code but adding the createNewCell-Thing he's telling me it's deprecated.

Comment: The non-deprecated version is `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`, as the documentation will tell you. Doesn't matter though, the old one should still work.

Comment: Tried both versions now and the addObject one too, but anyway there just on cell replacing the old one.